# Подключить DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

Пишу десктопное приложение на C#, которая по задумке должна подключать dll, уже будучи скомпилированой и работающей.

Как это возможно реализовать? И возможно ли вообще :)

Comment: Уточните вопрос, пожалуйста. Вы не знаете как зовут DLL которую хотите подключить?

Comment: Я сам буду писать DLL'ки, тоже на C# наверно (хотя не принципиально).

Comment: зеленый прогер. а что ты хочешь от них иметь? Они по разному подключаются.

Comment: такое ТЗ :), есть несколько "реальностей"(к примеру несколько примитвных игровых движков) и есть искуственный интеллект, который принимает определенное кол-во аттрибутов обрабатывает и отдает обрано в "реальность", и так по циклу. Искуственный интеллект и "реальность" должны быть написаны как DLL, и подключить можно было прям на ходу к WPF приложению (чтобы просматривать собсно результаты трудов интелекта) и проверить как себя будет вести этот интеллект с этим движком а потом и с другим. Тема DLL для меня новая, и все что я видел это подключение изначально с помощью добавлением ссылки на dll.

Comment: Но это не вариант, т.к. мы изначально не знаем какие dll подключать и где они вообще находятся.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Варианты предлагаю такие:

1. Использовать MEF (как в ответе выше)
2. Использовать MAF (как альтернатива, она может выгружать DLL налету)
3. Использовать Prism
4. Создать общую библиотеку с хорошо продуманным интерфейсом и классом (н-р `InitPlugin`); обязать ваши библиотеки иметь эту библиотеку и обращаться к нужным интерфейсам посредством `Reflection`.
5. Для неуправляемого кода можно использовать очень интересную возможность: дело в том, что когда функция C# с атрибутом `ImportDll` обращается к библиотеке, она ищет ее в определенных местах (в системной папке и нек других), но если не найдет, то обязательно также посмотрит в `CurrentDirectory`. Устанавливая `Environment.CurrentDirectory` на нужные каталоги, можно добиться системы плагинов на неуправляемом уровне.
6. Последний который приходит в голову, это компилить какие-нибудь алгоритмы прямо на лету через `CSharp Compiler`.

Comment: Вот он, ответ моей мечты! :)
Спасибо!

Comment: Да просто глянул что предложили только MEF, и подумал что грех не упомянуть и Это :)

Comment: с учетом прошедшего времени, могу заметить только, что MEF тоже умеет выгружать DDL налету, если загружает их в отдельный AppDomain

Answer (score 5):

Рассматривайте ваши бибилиотеки как "плагины" или расширения основной программы.

Начиная с 4 версии фреймворка в платформу .NET включен [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460648.aspx)

> Платформа Managed Extensibility Framework, или MEF, – это библиотека для создания простых расширяемых приложений. Она позволяет разработчикам приложений находить и использовать расширения без каких-либо настроек. Кроме того, дает разработчикам расширений возможность легко инкапсулировать код и избежать использования ненадежных жестких зависимостей. MEF не только позволяет использовать зависимости повторно, но и дает возможности применять их в различных приложениях.

Comment: MEF - расширяет домен,для выгрузки библиотеки нужен перезапуск приложения. MAF - это "плагины", которые могут быть выгружены, но подозреваю что не очень удобно и сложно с ними работать.