# Как подключить DLL Динамически?

Tags: c#

Вопрос очень тяжелый попробую описать:

Цель: Скачивание нужной мне dll'ки, и подключение (динамически или ещё как-нибудь)!

Сам вопрос:
У меня есть dll (Ionic.dll) - для создания архива файлов!

Я хочу залить эту dll например на хостинг, и от туда при скачивание чтобы моя программа могла соединиться с этой dll и продолжить работу: Как такое сделать?
Вот кусок кода отвечающий за архивацию:

```
using Ionic.Zip;

public class Archive
{
    static string US = Environment.UserName;
    public static void GO()
    {
        try
        {
                using (var zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    {
                        zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
                        zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.Always;
                        zip.AlternateEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                        zip.UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.AsNecessary;
                        zip.AddDirectory("С:\\Papka");
                        zip.Save("С:\\Papka"+ "_" + ".zip");
                    }
                    zip.Dispose();
                }
            }
            else { }
        }
        catch { } 
}
```

Подскажите лучший способ подключения dll динамически! 
Скорее всего dll будут рядом с проектом лежать рядом в 1 папке!
Было бы так же не плохо, сделать проверку,то есть если рядом с exe'шником нету нужной dll 
сделать исключение, если же есть то подключить и начать работать.

Comment: Смотрите примеры с LoadAssembly

Comment: [Подключить DLL](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/146526/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-dll?rq=1)

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону ILMerge - тогда и хостинг не будет нужен.

Comment: ILMerge не желательно использовать. Я пробовал не раз) Во 1 - Вес больше получается, Во 2-ых наблюдал некоторые ошибки при работе программы, именно из-за ILMerge!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можете добавить новый обработчик для `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` и подсовывать загружаемые Assembly там. Вот [тут](http://www.aboutmycode.com/net-framework/assemblyresolve-event-tips/) отличный набор советов, как сделать это лучше всего.

```
static void Main(string[] args){
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ResolveAssembly;
}

static Assembly ResolveAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args){
    return Assembly.LoadFile(@"path to the library");
}
```

Для случая, когда библиотеки под рукой ещё нет, оберните вызов метода, ссылающегося на любой тип из этой библиотеки, в try-catch. Даже если внутри метода лишь `if (false){ ZipFile totallyNotUsedVariable; }`, вызов такого метода бросит исключение.

Comment: _For example the following code will generate the exception (mainclass is defined in the library we are loading)_

Comment: @Grundy, упс, прошу прощения, проглядел. Хотел лишь привести простейший пример добавления обработчика.

Comment: Спасибо за конкретику)

Comment: @SurfinBird, надо просто повнимательнее быть

Comment: А например если dll'ки нету, можно просто завершить работу программы без `exception`?